# Should I consider using a VPS to host my web application?

Tags: asp.net, hosting, web-applications, vps

What are the disadvantages (if any) of using a virtual private server instead of a dedicated server to host my web application?

I launching my first web application in a couple of months and I'm trying to wonder what's the best way to host it at an affordable price. It's built in ASP.Net and uses SQL Server Express.

My point is, since it's a subscription based web application, which I don't expect a huge amount of traffic in the first months, will a VPS handle the trafic?

I've been looking around and I can find a VPS with 2Gb of ram for U$ 50, and that's way bellow renting a private server that I'm sure will be underused in the firsts months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the main disadvantages of VPS is you still have shared resources despite them touting, "dedicated processor".  While that may be true, you're still sharing a server with other VPS clients.

Nothing wrong with starting out there, especially if the service has a direct upgrade path to dedicated, should your web app warrant it.  Let's hope it does!  I'd love to have those problems.

Answer (score 1):

My gut feeling is that a VPS will work well for you. But I think your chances to get good guidance in matters like these increase if you ask the question over at [WebHostingTalk](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/).

Comment: +1 on WHT.  They have some very good folks over there and most of the questions that you could possibly have, have already been asked and answered.  It's also a great place to research hosting companies.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try it yourself? Download Virtual PC ([free download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=04d26402-3199-48a3-afa2-2dc0b40a73b6&displaylang=en)), build a virtual machine that's speced like the VPS you're aiming for, install your app and do some load tests!

This will give you the most accurate results, since it's exactly what the VPS vendor is doing.